# Last Sale for a given Machine

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to find the last sale for given device.

I have 2 tables

1. Machines
2. Sales.

They are join via `Machines.MahineID = Sales.MachineID`

Here is what I have so far :

```
Select Machines.Name, Sales.DateOfSale from Machines 
Left Outer join Sales on Sales.MachineId = Machines.MachineId
```

This gives me all sales for a given machine however I would like just the latest sale for a given machine. I would also like to know if a machine has never made a sale. Hence the Left outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need name and last sale only:

```
select Machines.Name, max(Sales.DateOfSale)
from Machines 
left join Sales on Sales.MachineId = Machines.MachineId
group by Machines.Name
```

if you need other columns from this last record:

```
select Machines.Name, Sales.*
from Machines 
left join (
  select MachineId, max(DateOfSale) max_DateOfSale
  from Sales
  group by MachineId
) max_Sales
  on max_Sales.MachineId = Machines.MachineId
left join Sales
  on Sales.MachineId = Machines.MachineId
  and Sales.DateOfSale = max_Sales.max_DateOfSale
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Select Machines.Name, Sales.DateOfSale
from Machines 
Left Outer join Sales s on Sales.MachineId = Machines.MachineId
where not exists (
    select *
    from Sales os                      -- Other sale...
    where s.MachineId = os.MachineId   -- Same machine
      AND os.DateOfSale > s.DateOfSale -- later date
)
```

There is a correlated `exists` query that checks if there are other sales on the same machine that happened at a later date.

Comment: is there a special reason for correlated subquery? wouldn't it be slow?

Comment: @deathApril The days of correlated subqueries being "slow" have been over some ten years ago. There is really no reason not to use correlated subqueries if they express your intentions well.